# How to call implementation of method from current class?

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a class like

```
class Base
{
    public function greet()
    {
        print "hello";
    }

    public function speak()
    {
        $this->greet();
    }
}
```

and a class like

```
class Extension extends Base
{
    public function greet()
    {
        print "goodbye";
    }
}
```

I have this code:

```
$extension = new Extension();

//Situation One
$extension->speak(); //This says goodbye

//Situation Two
$extension->greet(); //This says goodbye
```

I want Situation One to say hello. I am happy for Situation Two to say goodbye.

Is there something I can do (presumably in the implementation of speak()) to indicate that the implementation of greet() in Base must be used?

(In other words, Base is happy for extension classes to override greet() but when speak() calls greet() it wants it to use the known behaviour defined in Base, not unknown behaviour defined elsewhere.)

Comment: Everything is good but it is not php. Use use dollar `$`  US dollar

Comment: @Niklesh Thanks, too much switching between PHP and JS recently

Answer (score 0):

Since you want different functionality in different situations, create two class implementations.

```
class Base
{
    public function greet()
    {
        print NULL;
    }

    public function speak()
    {
        this->greet();
    }
}

class Goodbye extends Base
{
    public function greet()
    {
        print "goodbye";
    }
}

class Hello extends Base
{
    public function greet()
    {
        print "hello";
    }
}
```

One scenario.

```
$hello = new Hello();
$hello->greet();
```

Another scenario.

```
$goodbye = new Goodbye();
$goodby->greet();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect scenario to introduce yourself to Interfaces. In this particular case you'll need the following interface:

```
interface MyClassInterface
{
    public function greet();

    public function speak();
}
```

Simply don't call greet within speak method if you don't want to override it:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public function speak()
    {
        print "hello";
    }
}

class Extension extends Base implements MyClassInterface
{
    public function greet()
    {
        print "goodbye";
    }
}

$extension = new Extension();

// Situation One
$extension->speak(); // This says hello

// Situation Two
$extension->greet(); // This says goodbye
```

Comment: Surely your Extension doesn't implement MyClassInterface because it doesn't implement speak() ?